# Build a React App in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed [these instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) and I made a hello world app with React. I uploaded the development files in my EBS and it worked.

After that I used the command **npm run build**, I followed the instructions, I installed the **push-state** and I tested using localhost. Everything worked fine.

But I uploaded the build files to my EBS and it complains that the app does not have the **package.json** file and the app does not work.

What do I have to do to put in package.json to deploy my react app using Elastic Beanstalk? How to deploy the build files generated by **npm run build** in EBS?

Comment: [Tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html)  Try looking at an express app hosted by AWS beanstalk ...

Comment: Then add in react from the example

Comment: You don't need EBS to deploy your React app. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41250087/652669

Answer (score 4):

I recently deployed my react node based app using the EB CLI. I had to run `eb init` in my project directory which walks you through setting up the eb config. Here's the steps:

1. `npm init` to setup package.json (which you've done)
2. `git init` to setup a git repo
3. `eb init` to setup elastic beanstalk settings through its CLI
4. commit code
5. deploy to eb with `eb deploy`

[AWS walks you through these steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html) assuming you're serving your app with node (which you didn't say, but it's likely).

As a bonus, you might want to setup CI so that AWS builds your app when your tests pass on code push. See the [travis yaml](https://github.com/grraft/next-boilerplate/blob/master/.travis.yml) file I use to do this.

Comment: Can you provide the complete details about how to deploy react app in EBS