# Can I deploy a ReactJS application on EBS?

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I was working with EBS ( elastic bean stalk ), I saw nodejs as an option.

I have a website running with ReactJS on front end and Java/Tomcat as backend.

Can I deploy that app on EBS ?

Comment: Seems [perfectly doable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.java). Also have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772948/build-a-react-app-in-elastic-beanstalk) for react apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 100% doable. AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports almost all platforms. From Ruby to Docker. Also you can build your own custom platforms. Please go through the below links.

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk Tomcat Deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html)

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk Supported Platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html)